# Is connecting a MacBook air to a monitor using a USB-C to HDMI adapter bad for the MacBook in the long run?

Tags: display, power-supply, hdmi, macbook, usb-c

I have in the past used accessories that drew too much power from a device that damaged the device, which proceeded to have a lot of problems with it powering off by itself. (Those accessories didn’t require their own power input when used with a desktop computer.)

Now I need to connect a MacBook Air to a standard desktop monitor that only has HDMI ports. It seems that this can be done with a USB-C to HDMI adapter.

I know a USB-C to HDMI adapter is supposed to transfer data, but I’m not sure as to how much of a power demand this is on the laptop? The MacBook air is a very light laptop. Intuitively I feel I’d ask first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I have in the past used accessories that drew too much power from a device that damaged the device* Hard to believe but I guess it's possible. Solution: Use know good peripherals. Your question specifically about the USB-C alt mode makes no sense as it doesn't require additional power, it's the same as an HDMI port.